# TypeError: Blob is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node app for the server and a vue app for the client.
I want to create a pdf file and also send it to the user with nodemailer and also view it in the client application.
For this I use pdfkit to create a pdf document on the server side and then send to client and send by email.
To send to client I try to use the blob-stream directory.
But I always get an error or Blob is not a constructor
Or Blob is not a function.
If anyone has an idea what the solution is for me I would love to get an answer.
Thanks in advance
this is my code:

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const doc =  new pdfkit();
        const stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
        doc.text('hallo!!!!')
        .fontSize(50)
        doc.end()
        sendMailer(req.body.email).catch(console.error);
        stream.on('finish', () => { 
          const url = stream.toBlobURL() 
        }) 
      }catch (err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

Comment: What is `blobStream`? Also, does the error come from `.catch(console.error)` or `console.log(err)`? Also, if you add `console.log(url)` in your stream finish, do you see that?

Comment: The error is not due to console.log nor to catch.
But from a problem he does not know what a blob is.
thank you for the answer!